# Auto-Login chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension, authentication

I've been trying to learn some javaScript and I'm trying to autoLogin to my student's website coding a simple chrome extension. It doesn't seem to be working, do you know what i'm getting wrong? 
ty!!

---

```
<script>
            if (window.location.host =="MY_STUDENTS_HOST_SITE"){
                var button = document.getElementsByClassName("loginurl")
                button[0].click();
            }
            if (window.location.host == "MY_STUDENTS_LOGIN_HOST_SITE"){
                var username = document.getElementById("username")
                var password = document.getElementById("password")
                username.write("MY_USERNAME")
                password.write("MY_PASSWORD")
                var button = document.getElementsById("loginbutton")
                button.click();
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

To "write" the username and password, you can use the `value` attribute. You can change the value of an `<input>` element like this (I'm assuming the `username` and `password` elements are inputs):

```
var username = document.getElementById("username");
var password = document.getElementById("password");
username.value = "MY_USERNAME";
password.value = "MY_PASSWORD";
```

Comment: Thank you for you quick answer! I did what you told, which most probably fixed one of my mistakes, but I guess there are others bc it still doesn't work! (they are indeed inputs!)

Comment: Can you provide more information? What do you mean by "*it still doesn't work*"? Does it submit the form? Do you get an error message in the console? If so, which one? Does the login button get clicked?